# Additive Subspace Signature

Tags: signature

I realise there are homomorphic signatures for short messages, for instance with RSA encryption we have a signature scheme where $S(m_1 m_2) = S(m_1)S(m_2)$.

I would like to know if there's a signature scheme where the messages may be linear additive combinations of the basis vectors $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ and where, if $v$ is in the subspace spanned by the basis vectors $(v_1, \dots, v_m)$ and the signatures $S(v_1), \dots, S(v_m)$ are known, it is possible to construct $S(v)$ from them.

Comment: What security properties do you want these signatures to satisfy? Because the usual unforgeability property is pretty trivially broken if the attacker knows the signatures for the basis vectors.

Comment: Also, I edited your question to format the math symbols better and to (hopefully) clarify the phrasing. Could you please check to see that I haven't introduced any mistakes while doing so? If you find any, feel free to fix them and/or to revert my edits. Thanks!

Comment: An attacker should be able to create any signature from the subspace, but no others- thanks!.

Answer (score 2):

The following papers constructs linearly homomorphic signature schemes.

Pairing based signatures:

- https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/025.pdf
- https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/netcode.pdf

Lattice-based signatures:

- https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/453.pdf